# loading from json string with Node.create throws exception

Tags: kineticjs

on this page
http://entropy.tmok.com/~gauze/canvas/load.html

I get the error: TypeError: this._createNode is not a function

which relates to this function:

```
Kinetic.Node.create = function(json, container) {
    return this._createNode(JSON.parse(json), container);
};
```

the json string I am using is copy pasted from a stage.toJSON() call, when I break on that function above, the value of `this` is "Window load.html" according to firebug.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `new` when you create the Node.
So.....

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');​
```

...becomes...

```
var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');​
```

....and then it should work fine.